# Renaming file names from LookUp file

Tags: python, lookup

I am trying to rename files in a directory. The files in the directory are PDFs, JPGs, PNGs, etc. The file names all include `EmployeeNum_DocumentType`. Examples:

```
001234_Employee_Form.pdf
009876_Drivers_License.jpg
```

The looks up file (`Lookup.csv`) contains the employee info, like Employee Number (no leading zeros`), Work ID, First Name, Last Name, etc...

What I want to do is rename all the files in the directory. I want to replace the Employee Number in the file name to Work ID + First Name + Last Name + Document Type. So the file names from my previous example should be this:

```
ZMC3A76AK_Joe_Bob_Employee_Form.pdf
DYCXDVBY4_Bob_Smith_Drivers_License.jpg
```

I apologize for my incomplete script, but this is all I can come up with for now from the Google'ing I did all day yesterday. I do not know how to replace the Employee number of the file name with the data in the `LookUp.csv` file. The `*print(rowDict[0], rowDict[1], rowDict[4])`* is working though and printing from the `LookUp.csv` file.

```
import csv
import os
import shutil

# make an empty dictionary which will hold the keys
keys = {}

#open file
with open('LookUp.csv','r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"')
        # build a dictionary with the associated ids
        for rowDict in reader:
              keys[ rowDict[0] ] = rowDict[1]
              #print(rowDict)
              print(rowDict[0], rowDict[1], rowDict[4])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the columns of the CSV file really are employee ID, work ID, first name, last name, this should do what you want:

```
import csv
import os

keys = {}
with open('LookUp.csv','r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"')
    next(reader) # skip header
    for row in reader:
        keys[ int(row[0]) ] = '_'.join( row[1:4] )

for name in os.listdir('.'):
    eid = int(name[:6])
    newname = keys[eid] + name[6:]
    print( "Rename", name, newname )
    os.rename( name, newname )
```

I convert the employee number to integer to avoid the leading zeros problem.  You might want to check that the employee number is in the list (`if eid not in keys:`) to avoid an exception, especially if you have to redo this after a partial run.  You might want to comment out the `os.rename` call the first time, just to make sure it does what you want.  I sometimes have a script like this create a batch file (or shell script) so I can review it by hand and then execute it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I am getting this error message:

    keys[ int(row[0]) ] = '_'.join( row[1:4] )
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Employee_Number'

Comment: That's because your CSV file has a header, which you didn't tell us or show us.  So, add a `next` to skip it.

Comment: thank you. yes, the csv does have headers. Now I am seeing this error. I try looking at the csv file and the actual documents file names, but I do not see any names that has '.idea' - any idea where it is getting that error message from?
    eid = int(name[:6])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.idea'

Comment: nevermind...the script is trying to rename the whole directory. Pycharm created a ".idea" folder. Thank you for your help @Tim Roberts

Comment: `if os.isdir(name): continue`

Comment: Tim, I'm running into another problem. I noticed that the script errors out when the Employee number in the lookup file doesn't have an actual file to cross reference in the file directory. Is there a way I can tell it to skip that lookup employee number if the file in the directory doesn't exist?

Comment: That can't be a problem.  We're not looping over the employee numbers, we're looping over the files.  You won't even TRY an employee number if the file doesn't exist.  Unless you've changed my code, that is...

Comment: your code is the same...here is the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\rename 2\5.py", line 13, in <module>
    newname = keys[eid] + name[6:]
KeyError: 2357


I jumped to the conclusion because I saw that some of the references of the employee number in the Lookup file is missing or some of the file names in the directory doesn't have an employee number listed in the lookup.

Comment: This is **exactly** the problem I warned you about in my description.  It's not employees with non-existent files, it's files with non-existent employee IDs.  Use the "not in" test to catch this.

Comment: I ran a few print test on the variables...and even created another list for any missing keys. the missing total keys were over 1,200. So the lookupfile was incomplete. I am requesting a new lookup file now. Thank you for all your help!